# Is it possible to use function on different classes in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, sql, database, orm, symfony4

I was planning to use different entities for my project. And I created an entity project and entity users. I need to get all rows from every table, therefore I used:

```
return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(project::class)->findAll();
```

But soon, I will be working with different entities and I would like to create a function that will take in the entity name and fetch all rows:

```
private function ConnDB($table)
    {
       return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($table::class)->findAll();
    }
```

But I have different problems with this code. How to do it?

Comment: "different problems" does not tell us anything. What is the value of `$table`? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a plain string as the argument:

```
private function ConnDB($name)
{
   return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($name)->findAll();
}
```

And then use the `::class` dereference when calling:

```
$foo->ConnDB(MyClass::class);
```

Comment: Where should I store this function, because If I create it inside the controller class, and try to use it in different function (in the same class) it outputs the error class attempted Attempted to call function "connDB" from namespace "App\Controller".